# Syntax for Solr Query with Cassandra Datastax integration

Tags: solr, cassandra, intervals, datastax, facet

I'm trying to use DataStax Cassandra/Solr integration to do a facet query with both pivot facets and interval facets

My query look like this:

```
select * from data where solr_query='{"facet":{"limit":5,"pivot":"event_type,key","interval":"past_visits","f.past_visits.facet.interval.set":["{!key=visit_13_month}[NOW-13MONTH/MONTH,NOW]","{!key=visit_1_month}[NOW-1MONTH/DAY,NOW]"]},"q":"*:*"}']
```

The error that I am getting back seems to show that the required parameter is not being set (but it is)

08:30:38.244 [New I/O worker #4] WARN  c.d.driver.core.RequestHandler - /10.239.133.151:9042 replied with server error (Missing required parameter: f.past_visits.facet.interval.set (or default: facet.interval.set)), trying next host.

When i run an equivalent query directly to Solr (using query params), it works as expected.

```
/data/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot=event_type,key&facet.limit=5&facet.interval=past_visits&f.past_visits.facet.interval.set=%7B!key=visit_13_month%7D[NOW-13MONTH/MONTH,NOW]&f.past_visits.facet.interval.set=%7B!key=visit_1_month%7D[NOW-1MONTH/DAY,NOW]"
```

I'm trying to follow the Datastax documentation at this link:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchJSON.html

There seems to be something wrong with the way that I am creating the JSON for the Datastax Solr query, but I do not see what I should change.

Comment: poor formatting of the question, Please improve the formatting.

Comment: As of DSE 4.8.1 interval facets are supported.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently support facet intervals via CQL. Anyway, you don't need to repeat "facet", so it should eventually be something like the following:

```
select * from data where solr_query='{"facet" {"limit":5,"pivot":"event_type,key","interval":"past_visits","f.past_visits.interval.set":["{!key=visit_13_month}[NOW-13MONTH/MONTH,NOW]","{!key=visit_1_month}[NOW-1MONTH/DAY,NOW]"]},"q":"*:*"}']
```